# A question on values of 1-dim representation dicide the element of an abelian group

Tags: representation-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and let $g,h\in G$. I want to show that if $\phi(g)=\phi(h)$ for any group homomorphism $\phi:G\to\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, then $g=h$.

If $G$ is a finite group, the problem is obvious. But how about the general case?

Comment: Let $a = gh^{-1}$, start with a non-trivial character of $\langle a \rangle$ then extend it to larger and larger subgroups. If it fails to extend to $G$ at some point you get stuck with a character of $H$ which cannot be extended to any larger subgroup. This is where you can pick $b \in G- H$ and extend it to $\langle H,b \rangle$ to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: @reuns Great! Thank you!